# Query database where the desired match has spaces and special characters, but variable doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am doing some URL routing as follows:
`mydomain.com/category/name-of-item`

I have gotten this to work correctly with `query_vars`. I check the database with `$wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_data WHERE name = %s", $name));` and should the parameter name-of-item be found, the desired content will be displayed using information obtained from that row.

The issue is that I am comparing the database name field to the query_var (name-of-item), which obviously has spaces in place of hypens ( - ) and also contains randoms special characters for some items (apostrophes, accents for french cities etc.)

I have found a way around this as follows:

```
public function items_db(){
        global $wpdb;

        // Get items from parameter $name
        $output = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM item_data");

        return $output;
    }

    public function is_item( $name ){

        $util = new Utilities;

        $name = $util->clean( $name );


        foreach ( $this->items_db() as $row ){

            $db_name = $util->clean( $row->name );

            if ( $name == $db_name ){

                return $row;

            }
        }
    }
```

This is essentially getting every item from that table in a separate function `items_db()` and then pulling that info into `is_item()`, cleaning it with a seperate custom function which essentially strips everything to make the string one word, no spaces and no special characters, finds the match and returns the result.

The problem is, this is not efficient at all. The database is 4000+ items. How can I accomplish a similar objective in function `items_db()` by getting just the matching row?

I have tried `$wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_data WHERE name = %s", $name));` however I can't seem to have the query search the database for a clean, no special characters version of the column entry.

Comment: Why does your routing require such "fuzzy" matching to begin with? Is this actually rather supposed to be some sort of _search_ functionality?

Comment: @CBroe very good point. I actually thought about this a little after posting. Made more more sense and was more manageable to make the changes in my database table and go from there. Thanks for the input!